# Como mostrar por cada usuario los grupos a los que pertenece

Tags: script

tengo que realizar un script lo que tiene que hacer es que por cada uno de los usuarios del archivo donde se guardan todos los usuarios que muestre sus grupos, he hecho varias pruebas pero no me muestra nada.

gracias

un saludo[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Para cada pregunta es necesario que agregues un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que podamos ayudarte. Recuerda que puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/537802/edit) tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y que en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta.

Comment: y en vez de triplicar tu pregunta, [Pregunta1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/537794/como-mostrar-por-cada-usuario-los-grupos-de-ese-usuario) - [Pregunta2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/537782/obtener-una-lista-de-usuarios-y-por-cada-uno-de-ellos-mostrar-sus-grupos), espera a que te respondan